# deleting a line depending a value on a column do not work

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet :

[spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xlbLt.jpg)

I want to delete all the lines that have the value "VRAI" in the column A with this code :

```
  var PLsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("PLANNING_DATA");
  

  // nettoyer les lignes inutiles
  let rows = PLsheet.getDataRange();
  let numRows = rows.getNumRows();
  let valuesdelete = rows.getValues();

  let rowsDeleted = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) {
  let row = valuesdelete[i];
  if (row[0] == "VRAI")
    {
      PLsheet.deleteRow((parseInt(i)+1) - rowsDeleted);
    rowsDeleted++;
    }
  }

}
```

but it absolutely don't delete anything, and the weirdest things, is that when I change :

if (row[0] == "VRAI")

for an empty value :

if (row[0] == "")

it delete all the line who have "FAUX" in column A

thanks for the help !

---

### edit :

The word "VRAI" and "FAUX" are printed from a tick box and are the traduction of "TRUE and "FALSE".
if I replace manually the "VRAI" and "FAUX" value by a copy of the word "VRAI" and "FAUX", then it works... Apparently, the initial words are not really simple words
I find myself a little trick :

```
  var A1 = PLsheet.getRange("A1:A");
  A1.createTextFinder("TRUE").replaceAllWith("saucisse");
```

this is able to read the word "VRAI"... even if I ask for the english word "TRUE".
Then I replace it with a different word, then, I use the "FUNCTION DELETE" code...
anyway to make understand to my first code the same traduction ?

Comment: Please provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in the form of a sample spreadsheet and **not an image of the sample table**.

Comment: Also, I agree with @Tedinoz, your script also works fine on my side. Can you add more details as to what issues you have encountered on your side?

Comment: OK, thanks it help me to understand that it's coming from the fact that "VRAI" and "FAUX" are traduction from the result "TRUE" or "FALSE" from a tick box...

Comment: `raduction from the result "TRUE" or "FALSE" from a tick box` That is a VERY important point, but your spreadsheet still have the text values. Would you please edit your spreadsheet to use the checked or unchecked checkbox instead of the text values.

Comment: I mean that, when I ask .getValues(); the script return the value in french, I did not ask him to return the value in french rather them in english, I do not have the choice...
"Would you please edit your spreadsheet to use the checked or unchecked checkbox instead of the text values." -> I don't understand what you mean... it's already a tick box, and when I ask for the .getValues(), the script return the value in french...

Comment: Oh, i get it now. Have you tried using `if (row[0])` instead of `if (row[0] == "VRAI")`? If my assumption is correct, the value stored in `row[0]` should already be in the boolean format since you got the values from a checkbox.